# Trackpad unresponsive, or reverted and speed very fast

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, trackpad

My device: Macbook Pro early 2011, Yosemite 10.10.4

Since a bit more than a month now, I experience some problems with my trackpad.

At first, it would start to be reverted with very fast speed (basically, it's almost impossible to click somewhere you want to. It was happening from time to time, maybe 2-3 times a day, sometimes there was no problem for 1 or 2 days. A reboot would fix it.

Since a week or two, the trackpad gets unresponsive for few seconds before getting reverted with high speed, and sometimes (quite rarely actually) it goes back to normal.

It tried to reset PRAM, reset the SMC, unplug and replug the battery, clean completely the trackpad, unplug and replug both ends of the trackpad cable.

It always comes back. Since a few days it's more and more often. Like usually, a reboot fixes it but now, it might come back like 2 minutes after a reboot.

I just did a reinstall (just a reinstall, keeping all my data and applications), and it didn't fix it at all.

I noticed recently as well that the keyboard might be unresponsive for a short time but I thought it might be because of CPU use or whatever but I start to think it's link. Although it doesn't last long at all.

I don't know if it's a software or a hardware problem. I would be okay to change the trackpad and the cable if I was sure they were the problem.

Here are the logs from the Console when the problem occurs.

```
12/08/15 09:10:56,985 hidd[104]: MultitouchHID: Error 0xE00002C7 getting detection options
12/08/15 09:10:57,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceSetReport - DeviceRequest for reportID 0xac returned with result 0xe000404f - retrying
12/08/15 09:10:57,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceSetReport - DeviceRequest for reportID 0xac returned with result 0xe000404f - retrying
12/08/15 09:10:57,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceSetReport - DeviceRequest for reportID 0xac returned with result 0xe000404f - retrying
12/08/15 09:10:57,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceSetReport - DeviceRequest returned error 0xe000404f (interface 1, reportID 0xac, payload 2 
12/08/15 09:10:57,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: _deviceSetReport returned an error in configureDataMode
12/08/15 09:10:57,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::checkStatus - received Status Packet, Payload 4: device resetting
12/08/15 09:10:58,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_getFeatureReportInfo - DeviceRequest returned with result 0xe000404f - retrying (reportID 0xd1)
12/08/15 09:10:58,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_getFeatureReportInfo - DeviceRequest returned error 0xe00002ed (interface 1, reportID 0xd1)
12/08/15 09:10:58,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: _getFeatureReportInfo returned an error in AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReportWithLookUp
12/08/15 09:10:58,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_getFeatureReportInfo - DeviceRequest returned with result 0xe000404f - retrying (reportID 0xd3)
12/08/15 09:10:58,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_getFeatureReportInfo - DeviceRequest returned error 0xe00002ed (interface 1, reportID 0xd3)
12/08/15 09:10:58,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: _getFeatureReportInfo returned an error in AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReportWithLookUp
12/08/15 09:10:58,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_getFeatureReportInfo - DeviceRequest returned with result 0xe000404f - retrying (reportID 0xd0)
12/08/15 09:10:58,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_getFeatureReportInfo - DeviceRequest returned error 0xe00002ed (interface 1, reportID 0xd0)
12/08/15 09:10:58,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: _getFeatureReportInfo returned an error in AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReportWithLookUp
12/08/15 09:10:58,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_getFeatureReportInfo - DeviceRequest returned with result 0xe000404f - retrying (reportID 0xa1)
12/08/15 09:10:58,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_getFeatureReportInfo - DeviceRequest returned error 0xe00002ed (interface 1, reportID 0xa1)
12/08/15 09:10:58,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: _getFeatureReportInfo returned an error in AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReportWithLookUp
12/08/15 09:10:58,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_getFeatureReportInfo - DeviceRequest returned with result 0xe000404f - retrying (reportID 0xd9)
12/08/15 09:10:58,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_getFeatureReportInfo - DeviceRequest returned error 0xe00002ed (interface 1, reportID 0xd9)
12/08/15 09:10:58,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: _getFeatureReportInfo returned an error in AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReportWithLookUp
12/08/15 09:10:59,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_getFeatureReportInfo - DeviceRequest returned with result 0xe000404f - retrying (reportID 0xd1)
12/08/15 09:10:59,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_getFeatureReportInfo - DeviceRequest returned error 0xe00002ed (interface 1, reportID 0xd1)
12/08/15 09:10:59,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: _getFeatureReportInfo returned an error in AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReportWithLookUp
12/08/15 09:10:59,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_getFeatureReportInfo - DeviceRequest returned with result 0xe000404f - retrying (reportID 0xd3)
12/08/15 09:10:59,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_getFeatureReportInfo - DeviceRequest returned error 0xe00002ed (interface 1, reportID 0xd3)
12/08/15 09:10:59,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: _getFeatureReportInfo returned an error in AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReportWithLookUp
12/08/15 09:10:59,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_getFeatureReportInfo - DeviceRequest returned with result 0xe000404f - retrying (reportID 0xd0)
12/08/15 09:11:00,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_getFeatureReportInfo - DeviceRequest returned error 0xe00002ed (interface 1, reportID 0xd0)
12/08/15 09:11:00,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: _getFeatureReportInfo returned an error in AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReportWithLookUp
12/08/15 09:11:00,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_getFeatureReportInfo - DeviceRequest returned with result 0xe000404f - retrying (reportID 0xa1)
12/08/15 09:11:00,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_getFeatureReportInfo - DeviceRequest returned error 0xe00002ed (interface 1, reportID 0xa1)
12/08/15 09:11:00,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: _getFeatureReportInfo returned an error in AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReportWithLookUp
12/08/15 09:11:00,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_getFeatureReportInfo - DeviceRequest returned with result 0xe000404f - retrying (reportID 0xd9)
12/08/15 09:11:00,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_getFeatureReportInfo - DeviceRequest returned error 0xe00002ed (interface 1, reportID 0xd9)
12/08/15 09:11:00,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: _getFeatureReportInfo returned an error in AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReportWithLookUp
12/08/15 09:11:00,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: ReportID is invalid in AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReportWithLookUp
12/08/15 09:11:00,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: ReportID is invalid in AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReportWithLookUp
12/08/15 09:11:01,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: ReportID is invalid in AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReportWithLookUp
12/08/15 09:11:01,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: ReportID is invalid in AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReportWithLookUp
12/08/15 09:11:01,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: ReportID is invalid in AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReportWithLookUp
12/08/15 09:11:01,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::checkStatus - received Status Packet, Payload 2: device was reinitialized
12/08/15 09:11:01,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: ReportID is invalid in AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReportWithLookUp
12/08/15 09:11:01,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: ReportID is invalid in AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReportWithLookUp
12/08/15 09:11:01,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: ReportID is invalid in AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReportWithLookUp
12/08/15 09:11:01,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: ReportID is invalid in AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReportWithLookUp
12/08/15 09:11:01,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: ReportID is invalid in AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReportWithLookUp
12/08/15 09:11:01,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: ReportID is invalid in AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReportWithLookUp
12/08/15 09:11:01,088 hidd[104]: MultitouchHID: Error 0xE00002C7 getting detection options
12/08/15 09:11:01,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceSetReport - DeviceRequest for reportID 0xac returned with result 0xe000404f - retrying
12/08/15 09:11:01,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceSetReport - DeviceRequest for reportID 0xac returned with result 0xe000404f - retrying
12/08/15 09:11:01,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceSetReport - DeviceRequest for reportID 0xac returned with result 0xe000404f - retrying
12/08/15 09:11:01,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceSetReport - DeviceRequest returned error 0xe000404f (interface 1, reportID 0xac, payload 2 
12/08/15 09:11:01,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: _deviceSetReport returned an error in configureDataMode
```

Any idea? If you need more information, don't hesitate.

Comment: Well... changing the trackpad didn't fix it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me it seems like you've done everything possible to get that trackpad to work and it just won't. It sounds like the trackpad part has just simply gone out. According to your post, you know how to take your MacBook apart to get to the trackpad, so it shouldn't be much trouble to repair it yourself. Also, trackpads are typically pretty inexpensive, around $30. If I were you, that would be my next move.

Comment: Yes I ordered one with the cable yesterday. It did it again with the new installation. Well I didn't make a full clean installation in the way of I just copied back my app and preferences but I don't think that's the problem. I just hope now it's just the trackpad and not something else like the motherboard cause then... well I don't want to think about it...

Comment: Well, unfortunately then, it sounds like it might just be the logic board. Hopefully, someone else could tell you otherwise, but to me, that's what all the signs are pointing at.

Comment: I read my comment and think it might give confusion. I didn't received the new trackpad yet. And by the installation I meant installing OS-X.

Comment: Oh! You only ordered it. I'd say that putting a replacement in should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Use an external keyboard/mouse (USB) to isolate your internal hardware or software.

Also, boot into "Safe" mode to see if any of your installed software is causing a conflict.

From https://support.apple.com/kb/PH14204?locale=en_US:

Starting up in “safe mode” may help you diagnose problems you’re having with your Mac.

Note: To print these instructions, open Help Viewer’s Action pop-up menu (looks like a gear), then choose Print.
Shut down your Mac and wait 10 seconds.
Press the power button.
Immediately after you hear the startup tone, hold down the Shift key.
You should press the Shift key as soon as possible after you hear the startup tone, but not before.

Release the Shift key when you see the gray Apple logo and progress indicator (spinning gear).
To leave safe mode, restart your Mac normally without holding down any keys during startup.

Comment: It did it in safe mode and even when I tried to reinstall os-x. So I was ready to buy another one but since I reinstalled it (after a format) it seems ok (for now)

Comment: If you reformatted your drive, then you could have removed the problematic software.  Just re-installing the OS, without formatting, doesn't remove any of your third party software.  Hopefully that took care of it for you.

Comment: No it came back yesterday. But I didn't make the cleanest possible reinstall as I kept some of my previous applications the way I had them and some preferences as well. I ordered a new trackpad so I'll see.

Comment: It is not uncommon that they go bad; good luck with the repair.